# Write down an expression for the nth term of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

[Picture of the exercise I'm having trouble with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8djTl.png)

So I'm supposed to do Question 14, and I'm having trouble with a). The theory that I've learned related to this is algebra: proof by mathematical induction. The question is asking me to find the nth term, so I'm not sure how I can use the proving with induction method. I'm somewhat certain that I could do b), but a) seems impossible for me at the moment. I've been trying to find some pattern in the series but so far I haven't cracked the code.

Comment: $a_n=\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

Answer (score 1):

You can probably see that the numerator of our explicit equation is just going to be $n^2.$

As far as the denominator is concerned, note that the sequences $x_n=1,3,5,7,...$ and $y_n=3,5,7,9,...$ are just arithmetic sequences in which each subsequent term differs by $2.$ Recall that our formula for arithmetic sequences is $a_n=a_1+d(n-1)$ where $d$ is the common difference and $a_1$ is the first term in the sequence.

For $x_n$, $d=2$ and $x_1=1,$ so $x_n=1+2(n-1)=2n-1.$

For $y_n,$ $d=2$ and $y_1=3$, so $y_n=3+2(n-1)=2n+1.$

Putting this together, we get that $\frac{1^2}{1\cdot3}+\frac{2^2}{3\cdot5}+\frac{3^2}{5\cdot7}+\frac{4^2}{7\cdot9}+\cdots+\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

You could have also just noted that $x_n=1,3,5,7,...$ and $y_n=3,5,7,9,...$ are just sequences of odd numbers, and odd numbers can always be expressed as $2k+1$ for some integer $k$, in which case it is fairly simple to derive the formulas we did above.

Comment: Thanks so much! Good explanation.